# Touchpad crashes (?) after 10 minutes HP Mini LY931

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and my touchpad has started crashing after 10 minutes or so. It didn't yesterday. Just updated the system. First it behaves erratically then stops movement. USB mouse response is normal. All settings have been changed to other settings multiple times to no avail.

Comment: Can you define "crashing" a little more please?

Comment: First it behaves erratically and then stops responding.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with an old laptop I traced back to power and/or temperature issues.  I was able to solve the problem when I switched all my USB devices to a multi usb port adapter with external power source of it's own.  I also installed a fan controller and internal temperature monitor software / fan override on the system and that seemed to help.

Comment: Maybe that's it... Is there an Xorg log I can look at to see if that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using  Microsoft Mobile Mouse 4000 with Ubuntu 12.04 on a desktop.  My best solution so far is to use a usb extension cable to mount the rf unit closer to the mouse, within 3 feet or so.